# merge multiple fields of csv file while running mysqlimport command

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, csv

I have a mysql table like this

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| roll_no        | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| marks          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| academy        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the marks column can have multiple numbers separated by comma like this

```
45,67,78,80, # First Example
34,56,  # Second Example
```

I have to run mysqlimport command such that the fields after the first fields till second-last fields should merge into marks column

I tried something like this

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='roll_no, marks, academy' --ignore --local -u root -pxxxx result results.csv
```

But extra fields (after 3rd one) gets truncated. How to handle such scenarios where the csv fields are dynamic

Comment: Running on a unix-like system? Why not use some commands like `cut` or `awk` first?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a CSV file (Comma Separated Values), it thinks that the each of the marks is a different field. Your initial export should either separate values by a different char, like "#", or quot the values bu `"`.